# How to simulate python 2 str.lower() in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

There appears to be a difference between how python 2.7.15 and 3.7.2 perform the lowercase operation.

I have a large dictionary and a large list which were written using python 2, but which I want to use in python 3 (imported from file using pickle). For each item in the list of strings, there is a key in the dict for the python2 `lower()` case. Unfortunately, they're not the same as the python3 `lower()` case.

How can I get the answer to what python 2 would have returned to `unicode.lower()`, while running in python 3?

An example of a string in the list from python 3 is `'İle'`, the lowercase of which is `'i̇le'` (which incidentally, is NOT the ascii `'ile'`). This is not in the dictionary. From the pickle, what python 3 reads as `"İle"` is read into python 2 as `u'\u0130le'`, the lowercase of which is `"ile"` (the ascii string), which *is* in the dict. And that's what I need to return.

To clarify, I'm adding an example (where the latter is the ascii string).

python 2.7:

```
>>> u"\u0130le".lower() == "ile"
>>> True
```

python 3.7:

```
>>> u"\u0130le".lower() == "ile"
>>> False
```

Comment: Please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your description is unclear without the code.

Comment: Not sure if the difference is .lower() or one of encoding.

Comment: Following @JohnColeman doubt, I think the important part to show is how you created the pickle in Python2 and how you use it in Python3.

Comment: This is an actual version difference, as far as I can tell. [Python 3](https://ideone.com/iQJoor), [Python 2](https://ideone.com/iEFHRq). Python 3 includes a combining diacritic in the lowercase version.

Comment: It's not an encoding issue; Python 2 simply didn't implement `unicode.lower` correctly, AFAICT. Compare the result of `u'\u0130le'.lower()` in each.

Comment: On the other hand, the Python 3 documentation for .lower() says "The lowercasing algorithm used is described in section 3.13 of the Unicode Standard." -- something which has no direct analogue in the Python 2.7 documentation for that method, so it seems possible that this is a genuine incompatibility between Python versions.

Comment: The Python 2 version of the method uses "simple" case mappings (one character to one character, locale-independent, context-independent), whereas the Python 3 version uses "full" case mappings, or at least something closer to them.

Comment: You may need to translate the original string yourself; for example `'\u0130le'.translate({0x0130: 73}).lower()` returns `'ile'`.

Comment: @chepner: translate is an interesting approach I hadn't thought of. But my list is long and it might take a while to find all the cases. Really hoping there's some way to use the python 2 version of lowercase.

Comment: It should be possible to locate `str.lower()` in the Python 2 source and use it as a guide to write a function which is functionally equivalent

Comment: @JohnColeman: You can find `unicode.lower` in the Python 2 source easily enough, but it depends on the deprecated `Py_UNICODE_TOLOWER`, which has a lot of problems with using it to try to write an equivalent. For example, its behavior is platform-dependent (in a different way than it worked on Python 2), and it's a C macro, with no Python-level equivalent.

Comment: @jtbr: I suspect that there is a more fundamental problem going on here: if you have data that includes esoteric characters like the Turkish dotted capital letter I, the very concept of "lowercasing" as an operation is already *highly* suspect. You will probably *never* be able to build a general-purpose case transformation function; at a minimum you will need to use some kind of locale-aware mechanism. More likely, you should use a library built for this purpose like ICU.

Comment: @DanielPryden Good observation. The entire thing sounds like an XY problem

Comment: @DanielPryden The dictionary is in fact part of a pre-trained statistical model for "true-casing", that is taking possibly incorrectly cased text and correcting the capitalization. This is not a problem that can be solved perfectly. Although it is meant for American English, there is no shortage of non-English words that slip in, often with their original characters, and need to be handled. But the problem indeed arises because the original python 2 algorithm was premised upon putting the lower() of each string in the dict, but when using this from python 3, the lower() is _not_ always there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brute force solution.

Create a lower map in Python2 and then use this in Python3.

Python2 program to create the map:

```
f = open('py2_lower_map', 'w')

for i in range(256):
    for j in range(256):
        b = chr(j) + chr(i)
        try:
            low = b.decode('utf16').lower()
        except:
            low = str('?')
        f.write(low.encode('utf-8'))

f.close()
```

Demo of how to use the map in Python3:

```
f = open('py2_lower_map', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
_py2_lower_map = f.read()
f.close()

def py2_lower(u):
    return ''.join(_py2_lower_map[ord(c)] for c in u)

low = py2_lower('İle')
print(low)
print([ord(c) for c in low])
```

To be honest, this might have rough corners and is quick&dirty,
but mainly do the correct thing. It works on one example ;-)

Comment: This is awful, but in a good way so (+1). It might be a workable kludge for an ugly problem.

Comment: @JohnColeman Very fitting comment and very careful choice of words :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Unidecode](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/) library.

This library converts unicode to it's closest ASCII equivalent, which appears to be what you want.

```
>>> from unidecode import unidecode
>>> unidecode(u'\u0130le'.lower()) == 'ile'
True
```

EDIT: As pointed out by user2357112, this does not match Python 2.7's unicode.lower(). Python 2.7 uses the C library function `towlower`, so to exactly match that function you will need to use some interface to C (such as Python 2.7 itself as in mkiever's answer). If you don't need to keep any non-ascii symbols, however, this should work.

Comment: This is definitely not equivalent to Python 2 `unicode.lower`. For example, it discards the accent on á.

Comment: Thanks for this. While I can't mark it as correct since it's not a general solution (as @user2357112 noted), it does solve my problem. I simply do the following: `s_lower = s.lower() if s.lower in mydict else unidecode(s.lower())`. At least for my data, s_lower is always in the dict.